# vb.net JSON Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'

Tags: java, json, vb.net

```
  Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader


    Try

        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.simsimi.com/func/reqN?req=" + TextBox7.Text +"&lc=en"), HttpWebRequest)

        request.UserAgent = "User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        request.Timeout = 1000 * 30
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer()
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream, Encoding.UTF8)

        Dim rawresp As String
        rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)

        MsgBox(rawresp)


        'ListView3.Items.Add("Simsimi: ").SubItems.Add(jResults("sentence_resp").ToString())

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
    End Try
```

it gives an error : {"result":400,"msg":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"\""}

i test it on internet explorer and same error .. but on fire fox it works fine :(
what should i do?

i want to make a mini simisimi chat :(  it looks like the response default cam from internet explorer :(

my os is windows 8 and my vb.net version is 2013 ,, target framework 4.0

help please :(

thank you

Comment: What is the value of TextBox7.Text? The error indicates that you're passing a string that the Java webservice is unable to convert to a `long`.

Comment: http://www.simsimi.com/func/reqN?req=hello   .. try this on your firefox .. it will show json simillar to this ..

{"result":200,"sentence_link_id":31252250,"slang":true,"sentence_teach_uid":0,"msg":"OK","sentence_resp":"Ano ginagawa mo"}

so when i press the button it will get the value of the textbox and put it on the request 

.. i try this on fb api graph and  its working but on simsimi not working .

Comment: for what it's worth, when I open that link in Firefox or in IE, I get the same Java error you're seeing. Is there a developer's reference for this web service?